# spring scope for transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, scope

I'm a new Spring user.
I have a question about scope and transaction.

For example, there's a service:

```
<bean id="bankInDaoService" class="service.dao.impl.UserDaoServiceImpl">
```

Let's say there are **2 people** who want to bank-in at the **same time**.
And I already put **@Transactional** above for Hibernate transaction the method for bank-in purpose.

My questions are:

1. Since default Spring scope is singleton. Will these 2 people share the same values. (person 1 bank-in 500, person 2 bank-in 500)?
2. Will the @Transactional be effective? I mean let the first person finishes bank-in, and then person 2.

I'll be really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrongly understood the useage of @Transactional annotation.

@Transactional annotation is used in case where you want to get all or none of your transactions to be successful. If any of the transaction fails then other successful transaction will be rolled back. It is not for synchronisation.

If you have registration page where you take input for 10 fields and 5 are for table user and 5 are for table company and you are inseting both records from a single service function. At that time you should use @Transactional annotation. If insertion is successful in user table and fails in company table then the user table record will be rolled back.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that by default Spring beans are singletons. But this won't be a problem unless your implementation modifies some internal state on each invocation (which would be rather odd - typically a service method will just work with the parameters it's been given).

As I just alluded to, each service method invocation will have its own parameters; i.e.:

```
deposit(person1_ID, 500)

deposit(person2_ID, 750)
```

As you've said "at the same time" we can safely assume we have a multi-threaded server that is handling both these people simultaneously, one per thread. Method parameters are placed on the stack for any given thread - so as far as your service is concerned, there is absolutely no connection/chance of corruption between the two people's deposits.

Now turning to the @Transactional annotation: Spring uses "aspects" to implement this behaviour, and again these will be applied separately to each thread of execution, and are independent.

If you're looking for @Transactional to enforce some kind of ordering (for example, you want person2 to **withdraw** the exact amount person1 **deposited**) then you need to write a new method that performs both operations in sequence within the one @Transactional scope.